# VB Script to Rename Files?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, dos

I've written a very simple batch script that will do an XSLT transform for me, to translate a bunch of html files to xml files:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.htm) DO java -jar saxon.jar -o:"..\Front_Matter\%%i.xml" "%%i" "C:\Documents and Settings\Robert\Desktop\xsl\htm2xml.xsl"
```

The XSLT works fine, but just the file gets created doesn't have the desired file name, for example, if the original file name is "Happy Christmas.htm", I want the output xml to be called "Happy_Christmas.xml", so there are only just two things, first is to get rid of the .htm part of the original file name, the second is to replace the space by underscore.

The current resulting file name is ugly, like: "Happy Christmas.htm.xml".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, your code isn't VBScript, it's a Windows batch file.

Comment: @Helen:Sorry about that, I have it edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `%%~ni` instead of `%%i` to extract the base file name without extension.
2. Use the `%var: =_%` syntax to replace spaces in the value of the `var` variable with underscores.

So, basically, you need something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%i IN (*.htm) DO (
  SET basename=%%~ni
  SET basename=!basename: =_!
  java -jar saxon.jar -o:"..\Front_Matter\!basename!.xml" "%%i" "C:\Documents and Settings\Robert\Desktop\xsl\htm2xml.xsl"
)
```

Comment: Seems like the process is running into an infinite loop and no xml file is generated?

Comment: @Robert: I missed a trailing quote after `htm2xml.xsl`. Could that be an issue?

Comment: I did put that back in there, but still the same. Let me try run it again.

Comment: I did try again, still not responsive.

Comment: @Robert: Try removing `@echo off` and examine the output (e.g. the java command line, the file names etc). Is the batch file actually looping?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set oFldr = fso.getfolder("N:\Groups\TestGroup\UPS\")

for each ofile in oFldr.Files
  if lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "txt" then
    fso.MoveFile ofile.Path, ofile.ParentFolder & "\HRSC100.txt"

    Exit for
  end if
Next
*if you want vbscirpt then above will work*
```